Corollary to Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt's theorem
I am reading this paper where it says in the proof of theorem 4.3 "In general, it follows from the proof of [26, corollary 7.3.9] that whenever $S$ is a Lie subalgebra of a Lie algebra $L$ and $\mathscr{U}(L)$ is finitely generated as $\mathscr{U}(S)$-module, then $S = L$". I have tried to see what would happen if $\dim_K(L/S)=1$ and using the basis provided by Weibel, I get that if $e\in L\setminus S$ then $\mathscr{U}(L) \simeq e\mathscr{U}(S)$ hence is finitely generated but $L\neq S$, am I missing something?

Why would $U(L)=eU(S)$ hold? (What does the right hand side even mean?)

The proof in Weibel's book says that a $\mathscr{U}(S)$-basis of $\mathscr{U}(L)$ is given by the $e_I$ with $I=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ increasing such that no $e_{\alpha_i}$ is in $S$ for $\alpha_i\in I$. In that case, $e$ is the only $e_I$ satisfying that. The right hand side means that it is the $\mathscr{U}(S)$-module generated by $e$.

You misread the notation in Weibel's book, which is explained at the bottom of p. 225. Translated to your situation of an inclusion of Lie algebras $S \subsetneq L$, it says that if, say, $\{e_1, e_2, ..., e_n\}$ are a $k$-basis of a (vector space) complement of $S$ in $L$, then a basis of $U(L)$ over $U(S)$ is given by all:
$e_1, \dots, e_n; \\  e_1e_1, e_1e_2, \dots, e_1e_n; \quad e_2e_2, e_2e_3, \dots e_2e_n; \quad\dots; e_ne_n; \\ e_1e_1e_1, e_1e_1e_2, \dots e_1e_1e_n; e_1e_2e_2, e_1e_2e_3, \dots , e_1e_2e_n; \dots ; \dots e_2e_2e_2, e_2e_2e_3; \dots; \dots; e_ne_ne_n;\\
\dots$
(Remember the universal enveloping algebra has products, and these come into play here.)
In particular, in your supposed counterexample of codimension $1$ i.e. $n=1$, you still have an infinite basis $e_1, e_1e_1, e_1e_1e_1, \dots$ of $U(L)$ over $U(S)$.
